# Android Studio Alammanager in battery saver mode

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, battery, battery-saver

I need some help.

Alarmmanager only works for me if I turn off battery optimalization (saving) mode for the app. (with this permission: "android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS")

How can I fix it or is there an alternative solution that works reliably? All I need is a function that is definitely called every day at a given time. I downloaded an alarm clock app that didn’t need this permission and doesn't need to turn off this battery optimalization mode.

(I tested my app with a Samsung mobil, Android 9, One UI 1.0 )

Thank you in advance for your help!